# PDO BindParam not working on Like statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is my code:

```
$sch = '%test%';

$select_search_query = "(
        SELECT 
            GROUP_CONCAT(name, ' ', surname) AS result
          FROM users
        WHERE 
        (
            email LIKE :sch OR 
            name LIKE :sch OR 
            surname LIKE :sch
        ) 
        AND 
            id_p = :ff_z
    )";

$prep_search_query = $connection->prepare($select_search_query);

$prep_search_query->bindParam(":sch", $sch);
$prep_search_query->bindParam(":ff_z", $id_p, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$prep_search_query->execute();

$array_search = $prep_search_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r($array_search);

// The output is empty
```

After spending a pair of hours, searching for the possible mistakes, I finally decided to come out here, because I don't know why this is happening...

I'm programming a search page and it must works using PDO. The above code, doesn't works, however, the following one does:

```
//$sch = '%test%';

$select_search_query = "(
        SELECT 
            GROUP_CONCAT(name, ' ', surname) AS result
          FROM users
        WHERE 
        (
            email LIKE '%test%' OR 
            name LIKE '%test%' OR 
            surname LIKE '%test%'
        ) 
        AND 
            id_p = 1
    )";

$prep_search_query = $connection->prepare($select_search_query);

$prep_search_query->execute();

$array_search = $prep_search_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r($array_search);

// The output is a very long array
```

It seems the problem is located in the LIKE, but I don't find the solution, I've tested many things and got no results. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately  you can't reuse same placeholder when PDO `bindParam` like you did:

```
email LIKE :sch OR 
name LIKE :sch OR 
surname LIKE :sch
```

it should be something like:

```
email LIKE :sch1 OR 
name LIKE :sch2 OR 
surname LIKE :sch3
```

and then underneath:

```
$prep_search_query->bindValue(":sch1", $sch); //or bindParam I guess will work as well
$prep_search_query->bindValue(":sch2", $sch);
$prep_search_query->bindValue(":sch3", $sch);
```

Comment: This is right; this is a limitation with named bind parameters in PDO, we can't "reuse" the same named parameter. This limitation is *not* well documented.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem!